# Replace dotx placeholder with complex table data

Tags: c#

We have a requirement to use Microsoft Word document as a template where its place-holders will be replaced. It works fine for simple place-holder replacement.

However the complexity comes in, when we need to add in place-holder which will be replaced by table with number of rows depending on the data retrieved from database.

Currently we are doing it using C# codes by generating the data before replacing into the Microsoft Word template.

Is there any better approach for this? Or can we use SSRS for to fulfil this requirement?

The end result should be the same word document with its place-holder replaced by values from database.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at XML data binding in Word documents described here [Data/View Separation in Word 2007 using Word XML Data Binding and OpenXML](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/dataview-separation-in-word-2007-using-word-xml-data-binding-and-openxml/)

Basically, you can add content to a Word document which is located in an XML file distributed within the docx-package.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398244.aspx) MSDN sample might also help.

Personally I really like this approach, since it uses an already existing technology built in to Word rather than parsing the OpenXML myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
// fill the dt DataTable from the database
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

// just some test data
int columns = 3;
int rows = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add();
}
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[columns]);
}

// replace the placeholder with the table
for (int w = 1; w <= doc.Words.Count; w++)
{
    // check for the placeholder match
    if (doc.Words[w].Text == "PlaceHolder1")
    {
        Table t = doc.Tables.Add(doc.Words[w], dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count);
        for (int i = 1; i <= t.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= t.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                // add the 
                t.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = String.Format("PlaceHolder1 row:{0} column: {1}", i, j);
            }
        }
```